# Cant find signing Config in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image: Can't find Signing Config in android studio]

Android Studio Version is 4.2.1

Comment: Is the project compiled?

Comment: Yes, compiled and running

Comment: If you search around, there were definitely recent questions about this.  I can't immediately find it, though.

Comment: tried opening different projects and searched places still cant find... i'm using latest android studio